# Joining two tables using numerical columns

Tags: sql, join, number-formatting, presto, dbeaver

I am trying to join 2 tables using the numerical columns (order number), to identify the orders that are available in table a but not in table 2 along.

But when selecting columns of both tables, instead of NULL values where there is no match, other numerical fields are populated.

```
select distinct a.order_number, b.order_number 
from table_ a
left join table_ b on a.order_number  <> b.order_number
```

I'm getting the following result:

[image]

I tried doing `cast(order_number as varchar)` for columns in both tables, but I'm getting the same result. I am doing this in Presto server using dbeaver

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[LEFT JOIN with NULL, NOT EQUAL both of them showing unexpected result](//stackoverflow.com/q/53789657/90527)", "[Not equal <> != operator on NULL](//stackoverflow.com/q/5658457/90527)"

Comment: For reference: a query for rows in one table that aren't in another is called an "[anti-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_(%E2%96%B7))" (the complement of a [semi-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_(%E2%8B%89)(%E2%8B%8A))).

Answer (score 0):

You should test for a match to get NULL for non-matching data

```
select distinct a.order_number , b.order_number 
from table_x a
full join table_y b on a.order_number = b.order_number
```

Comment: Thank you, Why doesnt not equal operator work? and why other numbers are joined

Comment: Because  1<>2 is true for example. So not equal operator in a join will work exactly this way , it will return all the pairs of rows from a and b  where a.order_number <> b.order_number